# JasperReports: How to create a parameter which takes multiple values as input

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report in which there may be multiple values being passed for a parameter named *`Product_Type`*.
So that my query becomes something like this:

*`Select Id, name from temp where product_type IN ('prod1','prod2','prod3')`*

Answer (score 7):

You should **Product_Type** set the type to **java.util.List**

In your SQL use the IN function :

```
Select Id, name from temp where $X{IN,product_type,Product_Type}
```

- second parameter *product_type* correspond to the name of the field in the table
- third parameter *Product_Type* correspond to the name you give in the report

If you pass an empty list, $X{IN,..,..} evaluate to a SQL "TRUE"

In the iReport, when you test the report, you see a *invite box*. Type :

> prod1,prod2,prod3

Comment: This query doesn't work...gives an error
SELECT rownum,REPORTING_MON_YEAR,PROD_TYPE
FROM temper_tst
where $X{IN,PROD_TYPE,product}
AND Upper(MONTH) Like Upper('$P!{month}%')
AND Upper(YEAR) Like Upper('$P!{year}%')

Comment: I don't know what your engine is, but be careful because I think that it is case sensitive. You have fields named rownum,REPORTING_MON_YEAR,PROD_TYPE in the same table ?

Try to identify why it do not work... If your SQL engine provide a monitor console, look at the query sent by iReport. You also can try to reduce the query :

1) SELECT rownum,REPORTING_MON_YEAR,PROD_TYPE FROM temper_tst;

2) SELECT rownum,REPORTING_MON_YEAR,PROD_TYPE FROM temper_tst where $X{IN,PROD_TYPE,product};

(if you have a big set, also add LIMIT 10)

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried the java.util.list approach but in the query its still coming in with [value]. the in should look like ... in ('value1','value2')